# ImportError: cannot import name 'apiv1' from partially initialized module 'app.api' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying to get my API working with a Flask app but keep receiving circular reference warnings no-matter what I change.

I might be being silly. But I don't understand how the modules are only partially loaded.

I'm trying to implement the [factory pattern](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/), but struggling to do so successfully.

## Here is my code:

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

login = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from config import Config
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)

    from app.api import apiv1
    app.register_blueprint(apiv1)

    login.init_app(app)
    login.login_view = 'login'

    return app
```

`app/api/__init__.py`:

```
from manage import app
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
)

apiv1 = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

api = Api(apiv1, doc='/documentation', version='1.0', title='Docket API',
          description='API for Docket. Create users and todo items through a REST API.\n'
                      'First of all, begin by registering a new user via the registration form in the web interface.\n'
                      'Or via a `POST` request to the `/Register/` end point', decorators=[limiter.limit("50/day", error_message="You have reached the API limit for today")])
```

`manage.py`:

```
from app import create_app, db
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_script import Manager

app = create_app()

manager = Manager(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app.routes import *
from app.models import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Obviouly i'm missing something. But i'm not sure what :/

Comment: I believe `import *` is generally considered bad practice, and imports should always go at the top of the file.

Comment: You can get it even without factory pattern

Comment: In my case it was just that I had the new .py file inside a folder. Once I moved it placed it correctly to the root of the application, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `limiter` in your `app/__init__.py` file close to where you create `db` that removes the need for having the app imported into your `app/api/__init__.py`. Then `from app import limiter` in your `app/api/__init__.py`.

`manage.py` only holds a reference to `app` when `create_app()` has returned. But you are importing `app.api` in your `create_app()` and this module requires `manage` to be fully loaded first. That is your circular dependency.

`manage` is the entry point and therefore must not be imported by any module.